# find the maximal matching for a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I'm studying for a theory exam. And I don´t understand how maximal matchning for biparte graph works. Could someone explain how I can find maximal matchning for example for this graph or some graph without weigts. I understand that i can for example start with 2-c and I see that a and b is not matched but i don´t understand which I have to choose and how I have to match them later. 
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP8yN.png)

Answer (score 1):

For graphs of this small size, a maximum matching can usually be found through a bit of trial and error. As you said, let's match 2 with $c$. Now, 1 has to be matched with either $a$ or $b$, let's go with $a$, allowing us to match 3 with $b$. The rest should be straightforward. Note that the sides of the bipartition have different sizes, so we cannot hope for a perfect matching. A maximum matching for this graph will have size 5.